# How can I make my form take only a limited space?

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE

```
<ul id="cool">
    <li>
        <form action="/send.php" method="post">
            <p id="submit">XYZ
                <select name="server">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
                <br />
                <br />Nickname
                <input type="text" name="Nickname" maxlength="16" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />Email
                <input type="email" name="Email" maxlength="254" required="required" />
                <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS Code

```
#submit {
    width: 125px;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #cool:hover {
        background-image: url(nav-bg.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

So after trying to put a background on the code using :hover I noticed that the form width expands on the whole page while it is centered.I tried using width in the ul{} but that put my form on the left.
So my question is, how to make the form not expand on the whole page?

Excuse my code, I'm only a beginner, anything else I could provide you to assist you in assisting me (irony :P) please tell me.

Comment: use css styles on the form element

Comment: I added width:125px ; but that put my form on the left.

Comment: Offtopic, but your missing a `}` to close `#submit` in your CSS.

Comment: if you are looking for centering `width:125px; margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ul` is a `block` level element by default, it will take up entire horizontal space on the page, so you need to assign some `fixed` with to your `ul` element, and than use `margin: auto;` to center the `form`.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 250px; /* Approximately */
    margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pu4X9/)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it.

Edit: I have to wait 5 minutes before acceping your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than applying css on the

tag and ul, you should try giving your form an id and then apply your css on that. As for eg,

```
<form action="/send.php" method="post" id="submit">
  <p>
    XYZ
 <select name="server">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     </select> <br /> <br />
  Nickname
     <input type="text" name="Nickname" 
     maxlength="16" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
     Email
    <input type="email" name="Email"
    maxlength="254" required="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
    </p>
    </form>
```

and then apply your css

```
   #submit
   {
    width: 150px;
    align:center;
   }
```

Hope it works. 
You can also use "%" instead of "px".

Comment: Good answer, but make sure you use `margin: auto;` to center as we don't have any `align` property in CSS :)